# Trouble coloring histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm currently trying to color a range of values on a histogram using 'ggplot2'.  For this example I’ll use the ‘diamonds’ dataset.

when I execute the follow comand:

```
qplot(carat, data=diamonds,geom="histogram", binwidth=0.01, fill=..count..) 
+ scale_fill_continuous(low="#F79420", high="#F79420", limits=c(1000,3000))
```

I get thw following and correct plot:

[image]

But when I use another syntax with equivalent code, I cannot get the same result. Code:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat)) + 
geom_histogram(
    binwidth = 0.01,
    fill=aes(y = ..count..)
    ) +
scale_fill_continuous(low="#F79420", high="#F79420", limits=c(1000,3000))
```

Result:

[image]

Can you please tell me what I’m doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat)) + 
  geom_histogram(
     binwidth = 0.01,
     aes(fill = ..count..)
   ) +
   scale_fill_continuous(low="#F79420", high="#F79420", limits=c(1000,3000))
```

This will give you the same picture as the first one above.

Comment: Thank you, It works!

I gess the diference was in the `fill=aes(y = ..count..)`

Comment: Yes. Whenever you want to change the look of the "plotted data" (I hope it is fair to say so), chances are you need to write something inside `aes`. It stands for aestetics, after all.